# AWS Lambda integration with SES

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ses

I have tried to integrate `SQS`, AWS Lambda with `SES` (Email service). But I am not able send messages.

Even It doesn't create any `cloudwatch` logs for troubleshooting. Could someone  tell why `cloudwatch` logs are not generating?

I am expecting to see logs if email sending is failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is with that permission of role which attached to your Lambda function.  The role should have permission to access SQS (ReceiveMessage) and SES (SendEmail).

For troubleshoot, add following permission to the lambda role. This permission allows you to see the Cloudwath logs and identify the issue.

```
{
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                  "logs:*"
              ],
              "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
          }
      ]
}
```

if you want further clarification (Step by step), please check these videos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1jNJLJoP9s&t=400s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y57oIlK9mHc&t=490s

Comment: Thanks Sam. Yeap. the issue was with permission